# How to combine the fill and alpha aesthetics from two different geoms when using ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly, geom-raster

I am trying to add a relief to an interactive choropleth map. I saw that in a non-interactive setting this [can be done](https://timogrossenbacher.ch/2016/12/beautiful-thematic-maps-with-ggplot2-only/) using the `alpha` scale of `geom_raster` and the `fill` scale of `geom_polygon`. This works just fine:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

# load raster data
volcano_raster <- as.data.frame(volcano)
volcano_raster <- reshape(data = volcano_raster,
                          direction = "long",
                          varying = colnames(volcano_raster),
                          timevar = "y",
                          v.names = "alpha",
                          idvar = "x")[,c("x", "y", "alpha")]
rownames(volcano_raster) <- NULL
volcano_raster$f <- 0

# create polygon data
volcano_polygon <- data.frame(x = c(1, 25, 25, 1, 25, 50, 50, 25, 50, 75, 75, 50, 75, 87, 87, 75),
                              y = rep(c(61, 61, 1, 1), 4),
                              order = rep(1:4, 4),
                              group = rep(1:4, each = 4),
                              fill = rep(1:4, each = 4))

# create plot (works)
p <- ggplot()
p <- p + geom_polygon(data = volcano_polygon,
                      aes(x = x,
                          y = y,
                          fill = fill,
                          group = group))
p <- p + geom_raster(data = volcano_raster,
                     aes(x = x, y = y, alpha = alpha))
p
```

[image: Plot when using ggplot]

But as soon as I try to make it interactive through `ggplotly`, R complains that the `fill` aesthetic is missing:

```
ggplotly(p)
Error in `[.data.frame`(g, , c("fill_plotlyDomain", "fill")) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

To avoid this error I tried to add a dummy `fill` aesthetic. However, then `ggplotly` does not display the `alpha` shading:

```
# create plot (works)
p <- ggplot()
p <- p + geom_polygon(data = volcano_polygon,
                      aes(x = x,
                          y = y,
                          fill = fill,
                          group = group))
p <- p + geom_raster(data = volcano_raster,
                     aes(x = x, y = y, fill = 0, alpha = alpha))
ggplotly(p)
```

[image: Plot when using ggplotly]

I know from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37494785/using-alpha-and-manual-colours-with-ggplotly) that ggplotly can combine the fill and alpha aesthetics when using one geom. This also works in my case:

```
p <- ggplot()
p <- p + geom_polygon(data = volcano_polygon,
                      aes(x = x,
                          y = y,
                          fill = fill,
                          group = group,
                          alpha = fill))
ggplotly(p)
```

[image: Plot when using fill and alpha from the same geom]

Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to create a plot using `ggplotly` that uses the `fill` aesthetic of one `geom` and the `alpha` aesthetic of another.

EDIT:

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57027384/convert-alpha-aesthetics-with-ggplotly) describes a workaround through using `geom_point` instead of `geom_raster`. However, the `size` of `geom_point` (unlike `width` of `geom_bar`) is given in pixels and not relative to the resolution. As a result it's very hard to find the correct value for the `size` argument, making it rather impractical for an interactive setting.